# Code to detect option value does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, compare

I was attempting to do some string comparisons in javascript. I have seen several tutorials and examples but they do not seem to work. I am missing something fundamental?

Attempt 1

```
function addAspect(aspect) {
    var print = document.createElement('p');
    var ptext;

    if (aspect == "Option1") ptext = document.createTextNode("This is option1");
}
```

Doesnt work.

Then I found this example to which all readers said it worked fine

```
function addAspect() {
    var print = document.createElement('p');
    var ptext;

    var aspect = String(document.getElementById("aspectResult").value);

    if (aspect == "Option1") ptext = document.createTextNode("This is option1");
}
```

Doesnt work.

I also tried `.toString()` as well as the `'==='` exact match comparison.

Full code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addAspect()
        {
            var print = document.createElement('p');
            var ptext;
            var aspect = document.getElementById("aspectResult").value;
            if (aspect == "Option1"){
                ptext = document.createTextNode("This is option1");
            }
            print.appendChild(ptext);
            document.getElementById("mainBlock").appendChild(print);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select id="aspectResult">
                <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="addAspect()"/>
        </form>
        <span id="mainBlock">&nbsp</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the html for aspectResult?

Comment: do an alert on aspect on the line before the if statement and see what is in the popup - alert(aspect);

Comment: <select id="aspectResult"> <option value="Option1">Option1</option> </select> - one option so that hings can not get confusing. It is in a <form> element. Thanks. U.

Comment: the alert works, and it says 'Option1'

Comment: when you say "doesn't work" what does that mean?

Comment: The var 'print' works fine here though....tried it with a random piece of text

Comment: javascript use single quate only `'Options1'` and case sensitive. try to alert the aspect and see result

Comment: @ravi: that first part just isn't true.  In JavaScript, both double and single quotes can be used for string literals.

Comment: When I say 'doesnt work' i mean 'doesnt work' - it does not do what the language is saying. The syntax will tell me what should be printed on the screen, it is not printed, therefore it does not work

Comment: Alerts work fine before and after the if

Comment: @user: see my answer, nothing is printed because you're not printing.  You're creating a text node but not putting it anywhere!

Comment: @Andy E - I am, as I mentioned above I just have suppressed this part of the code - I have tested this part though by putting a random bit of text in instead of the value of the element aspectResult

Comment: print.appendChild(ptext); document.getElementById("mainBlock").appendChild(print); - mainBlock is a <span> - this code works perfectly though when I use a random piece of text instead of the value from element 'aspectResult'

Comment: the type of aspect came out to be 'string' btw

Comment: I also checked this on a different machine altogether - and it didnt work either...

Comment: The first two blocks of code are useless, both functions do not produce anything.

Answer (score 1):

First, a small introduction to how dropdowns work:

```
<select id="aspectResult">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
</select>
```

To read the selected value from the dropdown, you should do this:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('aspectResult'),
selectedValue = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

Then, you create the `<p>` element with a text node inside:

```
var p = document.createElement('p'),
txt;

if (selectedValue == 'Option1') {
    txt = document.createTextNode('This is option 1');
}
```

Afterwards, you can append the newly created paragraph to the container of your choice:

```
var container = document.getElementById('mainBlock');

if (txt) {
    p.appendChild(txt);
    container.appendChild(p);
}
```

[All together now!](http://jsbin.com/ivedoh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your function creates a text node but then does nothing with it, so you code *appears* to do nothing at all.  You need to append the text node to an element somewhere in the DOM:

```
document.body.appendChild(ptext);
```

---

Your full code appears to be working fine in IE9, Firefox 4 and Chrome 11.  See http://jsbin.com/ekura5/.

Comment: I have already done that, I simply did not show you this part. I have it adding correctly to the body - i have tested this part of the code out with a random string instead of the value of the element

Comment: @user: you should paste your full code - it's obvious at this point there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted so far.

Comment: Full code (i cant answer my own question) <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function addAspect() {
    var print = document.createElement('p');
    var ptext;
    var aspect = document.getElementById("aspectResult").value;
    if (aspect == "Option1") ptext = document.createTextNode("This is option1");
    }
    </script
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <select id="aspectResult">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="addAspect()"/>
    </form>
    <span id="mainBlock">&nbsp</span>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put in the lines for adding it to the span, but those lines are above

Comment: @user: you can edit your question to include this code in the relevant parts.

Comment: @user: your code works for me in several different browsers, what have you tested in?  See my answer for an example.

Comment: @andy e - I am running locally (tomcat) through Eclipse Helios...sorry where is your example answer?

Comment: I just tested on firefox here and it doesn't seem to perform either... :s  U.

Comment: I thought to try out a switch statement instead...this didnt give the desired performance either....I cant seem to find good information about the internal browser of eclipse helios!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the `ptext` to the paragraph, you need to add two lines to the end:

```
function addAspect(aspect) {
    var prnt = document.createElement('p');
    var ptext;
    if( aspect == "Option1" ) {
        ptext = document.createTextNode("This is option1");
        prnt.appendChild(ptext); // Add the text to the paragraph
        document.body.appendChild(prnt); // Add the paragraph to the document
    }
}
```

Comment: `print` is neither a reserved word, nor a *future reserved word* in ECMAScript.

Comment: @Andy E: Apologies, corrected. "print" is used in certain environments, however (and it tripped up the syntax highlighter too), so probably safer to avoid it.

Comment: @user291652: Did you look at the last two lines of code? I don't see those in your question...

Comment: I have those lines, if you look below you will see an abstracted code (ignoring senstive information that you cannot have access to)